# How to build Solutions containing MsTest test projects using MsBuild?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, mstest, gac

I want to build the solution from the command line, but when I run MsBuild in a machine with Visual Studio 2010 installed I still receive the following error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\**v3.5**\Microsoft.Common.targets`

Note the version number, you are getting the wrong version of the .targets file.  For VS2010 that should be 4.0.30319.  Not sure what you did to get msbuild started but be sure to use the VS2010 Command Line Prompt.  That might not be the end of your troubles, not sure, the assembly lives in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies, a directory pretty specific to VS.